# Store Monolog in database

Tags: database, symfony, monolog

I have been creating an application with Symfony 4.2, I want to save all logs in database, I'm using MonologBundle.

Monolog.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

I want to store data in database like this 
[image]

How Can I do this with Symfony.

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve that by creating a custom monolog channel (e.g. `doctrine_channel`) and handler (e.g. `doctrine`) to go with it. Update the example below as per your needs.

**Monolog configuration**

```
monolog:
    channels: [doctrine_channel]
    handlers:
        main:
            ...
            channels: [... !doctrine_channel]
        console:
            ...
            channels: [... !doctrine_channel]
        doctrine:
            type: service
            channels: [doctrine_channel]
            id: app.logger.doctrine_handler
```

**Service configuration**

```
services:
    app.logger.doctrine_handler:
        class: App\Logger\DoctrineHandler
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

**DoctrineHandler**

```
namespace App\Logger;

use App\Entity\Log;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;

class DoctrineHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    private $initialized;
    private $entityManager;
    private $channel = 'doctrine_channel';

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    protected function write(array $record)
    {
        if (!$this->initialized) {
            $this->initialize();
        }

        if ($this->channel != $record['channel']) {
            return;
        }

        $log = new Log();
        $log->setMessage($record['message']);
        $log->setLevel($record['level_name']);

        $this->entityManager->persist($log);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    private function initialize()
    {
        $this->initialized = true;
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM log;
+----+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | message  | level     | created_at          |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Welcome! | INFO      | 2019-02-07 19:00:00 |
|  2 | Go back! | WARNING   | 2019-02-07 19:00:05 |
|  3 | Help!    | EMERGENCY | 2019-02-07 19:00:10 |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then inject `@monolog.logger.doctrine_channel` (type hinted `LoggerInterface`) to your service or wherever you want to log something. This should work! Now, it is up to you to refactor/enhance as you wish.

Comment: it works but not like I want, using this code, for one action by one user always there's more than 5 rows saved in the database. I want for one action one row will be saved in the database automatically.

Comment: >>> `This should work! Now, it is up to you to refactor/enhance as you wish.`

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki - You are asking to "store logs in database" and this answer does exactly what you want/wanted. The rest is your responsibility so sure please go ahead and make the feature specific modifications to achieve whatever else you need. `for one action by one user always there's more than 5 rows saved in the database. I want for one action one row will be saved in the database automatically.` - This has nothing to do with what you asked and the answer. It is just a "bad smell" in your own code/implementation of a specific feature. I hope we are in same page now!

Comment: Can you tell me how you use it or typehint it please? I tried to use it like I did previously in symfony 3.4 with ->info or ->error and gettings errors like undefined method named "info" of class MonologDBHandler. It's hinted to @var LoggerInterface currently.